# C# accumulate in list with item same key

Tags: c#

```
namespace Datas
{
    public class OtOverviewData
    {
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }

        public List<OtOverviewItem> ListItems { get; set; } = new List<OtOverviewItem>();
    }

    public class OtOverviewItem
    {
        public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
        public double TotalOt { get; set; } = 0;
    }
}

List<OtOverviewData> otData = new List<OtOverviewData>(); //insert data manual

var otAccumulateData = otData; // clone data
```

I want to accumulate `TotalOt` when same Year, EmployeeCode and (month increment) to otAccumulateData

Example:

- data month 2 = data month 1 + data month 2 (same year and employee code)
- data month 3 = data month 1 + data month 2 + data month 3(same year and employee code)

Thanks for your strong support!

I try using for loop but performance is slow.

Comment: Are these DTO's from a database? You should filter/group there.. You don't want to retreive all rows from the database and sort them out in C#.

Comment: raw data from ef core. this format in above define by me. i convert raw data to this format